# Postgres 14.3 created user authentication failed

Tags: postgresql

I am new to this SQL stuff and I recently installed Postgres 14.3 on my windows machine as part of an online learning requirement. I created a database and a user to connect to the database in the following lines from the shell:

```
postgres=# create database staff;
postgres=# create user Naruto with encrypted password 'secret';
postgres=# grant all privileges on database staff to Naruto;
postgres=# \c staff Naruto;

password for user Naruto:
```

After inputting the password I get an error message like this

> connection to server at "local host" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Naruto"
> Previous connection kept

Whereas the video description from which I am taking tutorials didn't ask for a password prompt but it connected to the database straight up with the designated user.

I have tried numerous suggestions on stack overflow but still, no breakthrough in any way. I'd appreciate any hint because I haven't recorded any progress with my learning recently. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The user you created is named "naruto", not "Naruto", because identifiers are case-folded when not inside double quotes.  In the `\c`, however, it is not case folded because at that point is not an identifier, it is more like a command line argument.

Depending on the contents of pg_hba.conf, PostgreSQL might not tell you when you try to login as a nonexistent user.  Instead it goes through the motions of authentication, even though authentication is doomed to fail.  This is so that an attacker cannot determine which users exist by trying a bunch and looking at the error messages.  The real reason for failure is published to the db server's log file, so if you had looked there you should have seen `role "Naruto" does not exist`.

If you want the user to have a capital letter, put double quotes around the name when you do the CREATE. Alternatively given that you already created the user without the cap, connect to it using the lower-case spelling.  And either way, look in the servers log file when you run into problems.

Comment: The issue has been fixed. Thank you so much @jjanes for the heads up !!! Please, how can I locate the db server's log file?

Comment: If you can and do not mind post yout solution. This helps future questioners facing the same issue.

Comment: Logging is very configurable, but the default for me when using the EDB installer for Windows is in the directory "c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/data/log/"

Comment: Thank you so much once again! I appreciate you taking the time to get this problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help someone in the future. All I had to do was fix the caps for the user I initially created as 'Naruto' and it got executed smoothly.

`postgres=# create database staff;`
`postgres=# create user naruto with encrypted password 'secret';`
`postgres=# grant all privileges on database staff to naruto;`
`postgres=# \c staff naruto;`